# Magento 2 message not showing after adding Google Recaptcha

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have developed a custom module for displaying a contact form. On form submission, I am sending an email and redirecting back to the same page with a success message. The message was showing until I integrated a Google recaptcha as described here https://magently.com/blog/recaptcha-in-magento-custom-form/. After that the message is not showing. If I remove the captcha it works. I have added message using below code.

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess('Email sent successfully');
$this->_redirect('pricequoteform/index');
```

Comment: Any issue in console after adding recaptcha?

Comment: No. There is no error in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you put your logic in the Action controller when saving the Captcha response?

If it is controller then you are using the wrong strategy as **messageManager** is used in two terms:

- via page refreshed
- via a page load or an ajax call

So make sure you Google Recaptcha Action is using messageManager and then send the message.

like:

```
protected messageManager;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    ...
){
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    ...
}
```

and then use:

```
$this->messageManager->addSuccess(__("Success"));
```

Or what you can do in Action controller is:

```
 public function execute() {
   $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Success!'));
   $redirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
   $redirect->setUrl('/captchaForm');
   return $redirect;
```

}

If it's good to you, that will be good meanwhile you can follow this extension also: https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-google-recaptcha may be it can be helpful to you.

Comment: I am new to Magento. Don't have any idea. I just followed the tutorial. It uses Magento's default Google ReCaptcha.

Comment: Used second method `$redirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();$redirect->setPath('pricequoteform/index');` and it worked. Thanks!